# setCellStyle not applicable

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, styling

I've been styling our excel file that could be downloaded when needed. What I have tried:

```
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.BIG_SPOTS);
column.setRowStyle(style);
```

The output is the row has been highlighted but not the main table that has contents. I think it is because of setRowStyle(). However, whenever I try to use setCellStyle() it says
[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Ox9.png).

Also, whenever I use add cast to column:

```
((Cell) column).setCellStyle(style);
```

It has an error.

Added. For the column variable. This is where it came from:

```
Row column = sheet.createRow(5);
column.createCell(1).setCellValue("ITEM");
column.createCell(5).setCellValue("Beginning");
column.createCell(6).setCellValue("Cost/Unit");
column.createCell(7).setCellValue("Subtotal");
column.createCell(8).setCellValue("Ending");
column.createCell(9).setCellValue("Cost/Unit");
column.createCell(10).setCellValue("Subtotal");
```

Comment: What is the type of `column`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i added it to the post thanks

Comment: `((Cell) column).setCellStyle(style)` wont work as you are having a row. You would need to iterate over all the cells within that row to call `setCellStyle(style)`. Something like `for(Cell cell : column) cell.setCellStyle(style);` should work

Answer (score 0):

I used XtremeBaumer's suggestion and it worked.
Syntax:

```
for(Cell cell : column) cell.setCellStyle(style);
```